# Why is $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t) \delta_{n}(t-x)dt$ ?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

In Arfken's "Mathematical Methods for Physicists", in Section 20.2 "Fourier Transform":

It is said that "We write the *fairly obvious* equation $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t) \delta_{n}(t-x)dt$..." where $\delta_{n}(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-n}^{+n} e^{i\omega t} d\omega$ (delta function).

I don't understand why $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t) \delta_{n}(t-x)dt$. Could someone explain?

Comment: An intuitive argument is to recognize this as $f \ast \delta$, and $\delta = \mathcal{F}(1)$. Then compute $$\mathcal{F}^2 (f \ast \delta) = \mathcal{F} (\hat{f} \cdot 1).$$

Comment: Both $\mathcal{F}$ and $\hat{f}$ are very standard symbols for the Fourier transform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short, non-rigorous "physicist's proof" is as follows:

We can compute $$ \delta_n(t) = \frac{1}{\pi t}\sin(n t).$$ Then, we have $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\delta_n(t-x)dt = \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \frac{1}{\pi (t-x)}\sin(n(t-x))dt \\ = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{n\to \infty}f\left(x  + \frac{u}{n}\right)\frac{\sin(u)}{u}du \\ =f(x)\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin u}{u}du = f(x).$$

Comment: How did you get: $\delta_n(t) = \frac{1}{\pi t}\sin(n\omega t)$ ?

Comment: Just did the integral. If you're uncomfortable with how to handle the $e^{i\omega t},$ you can remember that the real part is $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^n \cos(\omega t) d\omega= \frac{1}{\pi t}\sin(n\omega t)$ and the imaginary part is $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^n \sin(\omega t) d\omega= 0.$

Comment: @qbert good question. Fixed it.

Comment: no problem, it was clearly a typo. +1